# How to get everything except the fragment (row number) from an android content provider uri?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I would like to retrieve a ContentURI with appended id and be able to strip the id out.

In other words, I have a Content URI such as:

```
   org.mycontentproviderAuthority/path1/path2/3
```

and I would like to get

```
   org.mycontentproviderAuthority/path1/path2/
```

Is it possible to do that preferably with Uri methods? I mean I guess I could use a String tokenizer to remove the last digit, but Id assume that a uri api for that would be safer.

I tried  uri.getAuthority() + uri.getPath() but that gives me back the whole ContentUri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use the following:

```
static public Uri getUriWithoutLastNPathParts(final Uri uri, final int n) {
    final List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();
    final String[] newSegments = new String[segments.size() - n];

    final Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.encodedAuthority(uri.getAuthority());
    builder.encodedPath(uri.getPath());
    builder.encodedQuery(uri.getQuery());

    // no "appendPath", it messes up the thing
    for (int i = 0; i < newSegments.length; i++) {
        newSegments[i] = segments.get(i);
    }
    builder.encodedPath(TextUtils.join("/", newSegments));

    return builder.build();
}
```

Usage:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("org.mycontentproviderAuthority/path1/path2/3");
Log.i("Segments", uri + " " + getUriWithoutLastNPathParts(uri, 1));

uri = Uri.parse("org.mycontentproviderAuthority/path1/path2/3?foo=bar");
Log.i("Segments", uri + " " + getUriWithoutLastNPathParts(uri, 2));
```

Comment: I was actually wondering if there would be a "one method call" way to do it, but it seems not. I guess the reason it doesnt exist is because in theory the user should be able to reproduce the URI (without the appened ID) through the contract classes. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to parse the ID from a Content URI
http://appulearn.blogspot.com/2012/05/getting-android-id-from-uri-content.html

Comment: in my case I want to get everything from the URI except (minus) the id.

Comment: Id will be returned with uri.getPath() because Id forms the last part of the path. I am not sure if there is any way to get URI minus the Id other than string manipulation. I could be wrong though.